How can I install the historical version of `visual-studio-code-bin` on Manjaro?
Hi I just updated to newest visual-studio-code-bin and it crashes and put up my issue.
I've googled and most of the solution was to revert it back to version 1.89 and wait for it to update.
However, I searched across the internet and cannot find a way of installing historical version of it.
So if anyone could help on installing historical version of visual-studio-code-bin??

Just found the steps, providing to those who would need it:

Goto AUR page for the package:
Click View Changes
Pick target published version:
Click download:
Unzip the downloaded file
CD into the unzipped directory, run makepkg -si

